# XAMPP, Error: Mysql shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
 - 2:13:04 PM  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.    
 - 2:13:04 PM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
 - 2:13:04 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.   
 - 2:13:04 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check    
 - 2:13:04 PM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues    
 - 2:13:04 PM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this    
 - 2:13:04 PM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums
```

This is my mysql_error.log file

[image]

Please help me this problem

Comment: your error message says there's another application running on the same port